# How to increase time window for Jenkins TimeLine graph

Tags: jenkins

In the Jenkins main page, I have a link called "Build History" that builds Timeline chart with the chronology of all builds. Link is:

```
http://myhost:8080/jenkins/view/All/builds
```

It looks like the following:
[image]
I use it a lot as I can see in one chart how many failures occurred.
My problem is that history starts at 2AM, I can guarantee I have a job execution every day at 1AM, and I can not see it here.
In the end I would like to have a least the last 24 hours each time, but I did not find any configuration menu for this. I don't even know if it's from a plugin I installed or native in Jenkins.
Does anyone know how to increase the time window ? (or give me an indication on where to search ...)

Comment: I believe I have found the issue in [Jenkins JIRA](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17405)

Comment: I'm still having this issue with Jenkins 2.249.2 - only 20 build results are displayed in the global history timeline.

Comment: In that ticket, it looks like they fixed a bug, and it increased the number of shown jobs to 20.  And they were content with that and closed the ticket: "fixed in 1.58. It will now show 20 builds on the time line widget regardless of how many days."

Comment: Another ticket was created in 2019 to increase the limit beyond 20, but nothing was done: https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-60539

Answer (score 2):

You are talking about the greyish window, not the table below, right?

This is a 2 part slider with a viewfinder at the top middle.

The lower (darker grey shade) part is in **hours**. It fits about 4.5 hours in the view.
The upper (middle grey shade) part is in **days**. It fits about 4.5 days in the view.
The top middle (lightest grey shade) part is showing on the upper (days) graph the relative position of the 4.5-hour window that you are currently viewing on the lower (hours) graph.

You can scroll the graphs either by clicking and dragging left/right, or by pointing the mouse there and using the mouse scroll. Since the lower graph is relative to the upper graph, the scrolling is linked too: you can scroll in large chunks using the upper graph, and scroll in smaller finer increments using the lower graph.

If you are having issues seeing anything on the lower graph, then look for little vertical bars on the upper graph (scroll if you need to). Position those within the lightest grey area in the middle (let's call it the "viewfinder"), and you will see a list of jobs in the lower part.

While I haven't seen a way to increase the default window from the default 4.5-hour view, you can easily scroll it left/right to view the past 24 hours.

Comment: That's it, but even if I scroll, I can not see runs before midnight, it is just empty.

Comment: You have no history of builds before midnight? This view will only show the builds that retain their history. You said your build retention is already at 365 days, but do you actually see builds from before midnight on the individual jobs? "Lots of builds" doesn't necessary mean "builds from before midnight". Maybe your environment has some kind of OS backup/cleanup routine that wipes builds details after midnight.

Comment: nope, I really have a lot of builds history, for months

Comment: Does the table below the graph show anything beyond midnight?

Comment: As of now I can see in the list below builds since 2PM today, but in the graph it still starts at midnight. So it does not appear related (I have added a pic in my question.)

Comment: Updated my edscription, it's actually starting at 2AM as I have a job runnign at 1AM every day

Answer (score 1):

You can scroll (Left/Right) the upper part in the below figure to see the history.

[image: SNAPSHOT]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already have set all these to 365 days and I can see in each job's build history a lot of builds, but I don't see it in the global history chart I am talking about. I believe we are not talking about the same thing, did you try the link I have indicated on your Jenkins ?

Comment: Edited the answer. I guess this is what you are talking about.

Comment: Yes that's it, I can scroll very far, but before midnight, no more runs appear ...

Comment: You can scroll the bottom part as well to see the runs before midnight. But in any case, before midnight means the previous date, you can scroll to previous date to look for the builds.

Comment: Yes I did scroll, there is  nothing. Just know that on my jenkins there is not an hour without a build, even at night.
You can also see in my screenshot the above part show blue lines only after midnight. There must be a setting somewhere for this ! but I can't find it.